# (Anti-)Fundamental Representation of $SU(5)$ GUT

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebra, yang-mills, trace, grand-unification

In many places, it has been mentioned that the sum of electrical charges of the particles present in $\overline{5}$ of $SU(5)$ is zero since the trace of $SU(5)$ generators is zero. I do not understand how.
$$
\overline{5}=\begin{pmatrix}
    \overline{d}_{1,L}\\
     \overline{d}_{2,L}\\
      \overline{d}_{3,L}\\
      \nu_{e,L}\\
      e_L
\end{pmatrix}; \ \ Q_{\overline 5}=3\times 1/3 - 1 = 0
$$
Can anyone explain about the relation between the traceless-ness and the sum of electrical charges being zero?

Answer (score 1):

In a somewhat different notation than this classic [review](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Grand_unification#:%7E:text=Paul%20Langacker%20(2012)%2C%20Scholarpedia,%2C%207(10)%3A11419.&text=Grand%20unification%20refers%20to%20gauge,combined%20in%20the%20same%20multiplets.),
the
$$
\overline{5}=\begin{pmatrix}
    \overline{d_R}_{r}\\
     \overline{d_R}_{g}\\
      \overline{d_R}_{b}\\
      \nu_{e,L}\\
      e_L
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
with the SU(2) singlets in the upper three components and the leptons in the last two, is acted upon by the two diagonal traceless, normalized generators,
$$
T_3= \operatorname{diag}(0,0,0,1/2,-1/2) ~~~\implies  \operatorname{Tr}T_3^2= 1/2, \\
Y_1= \operatorname{diag}(-2,-2,-2,3,3)/\sqrt{60} ~~~\implies  \operatorname{Tr}Y_1^2= 1/2.  
$$
So the diagonal elements are the eigenvalues of the fermions in the quintet, and they sum to 0.

The conventional hypercharge *Y* in the "modern notation”, $Y= Q-T_3$, lacks the above normalization, so it needs $Y= -\sqrt{5\over 3}Y_1= \operatorname{diag}(1/3,1/3,1/3,-1/2,-1/2)$.

Consequently,
$$
Q=T_3+Y=\operatorname{diag}(1/3,1/3,1/3,0,-1),
$$
traceless, alright, like its terms.

Comment: So we can say that 1/3,1/3 1/3, 0 and 1 are the eigenvalues of the charge operator $Q$ and thus the sum of charges would always be 0, right?

Comment: 0 and -1. Right.